# Error 500 al llamar a API REST (GET)

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

Buenos días: estoy desarrollando un procedimiento por el cuál hago una llamada desde javascript a un api desarrollado en NET 6 (c sharp) y el tema es que en desarrollo funciona perfectamente, pero cuando publico la aplicación devuelve el error 500.

Código javascript:

```
        var url = '/api/RefCatastral/__id__';
        url = url.replace('__id__', String(refCat.value));
        var ruta = url;

        var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xmlHttp.open('GET', url, false); // false for synchronous request
        xmlHttp.send(null);
        var refCat_valor = xmlHttp.responseText;

        //Se recuperan cada uno de los campos por separado
        var coorRefCatastral = refCat_valor.split(";");
```

El código que se ejecuta en el API es.

```
 // GET api/<RefCatastralController>/5
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public string Get(string id)
    {
        string result = RefCatastral(id);
        return result;
    }

public string RefCatastral(string refCat)
    {

        //Se recogen solamente los 14 primeros caracteres
        if (refCat.Length > 14)
        {
            refCat = refCat.Substring(0, 14);
        }

        //string url = "https://ovc.catastro.meh.es/ovcservweb/OVCSWLocalizacionRC/OVCCoordenadas.asmx/Consulta_CPMRC?Provincia=&Municipio=&SRS=&RC=10199A02700056";
        string url = "https://ovc.catastro.meh.es/ovcservweb/OVCSWLocalizacionRC/OVCCoordenadas.asmx/Consulta_CPMRC?Provincia=&Municipio=&SRS=&RC=" + refCat;

        string URLString = url;
        XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(URLString);

        string Elemento = "";
        string Valor = "";

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            switch (reader.NodeType)
            {
                //Buscamos xcen, ycen y srs (EPSG:25829 y EPSG:25830)
                case XmlNodeType.Element: // The node is an element.
                    Elemento = reader.Name;

                    //while (reader.MoveToNextAttribute()) // Read the attributes.
                    //    Console.Write(" " + reader.Name + "='" + reader.Value + "'");
                    //Console.Write(">");
                    //Console.WriteLine(">");
                    break;
                case XmlNodeType.Text: //Display the text in each element.                       
                    if ((Elemento == "xcen") || (Elemento == "ycen") || (Elemento == "srs"))
                    {
                        string ValorTrabajado = "";
                        if (Elemento == "srs")
                        {
                            ValorTrabajado = reader.Value.Substring(reader.Value.Length - 2);
                        }
                        ValorTrabajado = ValorTrabajado == "" ? reader.Value.ToString() : ValorTrabajado;
                        Valor = Valor + ";" + ValorTrabajado;
                    }
                    break;
                case XmlNodeType.EndElement: //Display the end of the element.

                    break;
            }
        }
        if (Valor.Length > 2)
            Valor = Valor.Substring(1);

        return Valor;
    }
```

La pregunta es ¿Cómo puedo hacer que funcione una vez que lo publico y no me salte el error 500? ¿Es mejor seguir otro camino?

Gracias, un saludo.

Comment: Cuando dices *"que te da error cuando publicas"*, tienes que comentarnos en que entorno? en un servidor con IIS? tienes instalado el [runtime de .NET](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download) en dicho servidor? o estas hosteandolo en algun lugar en la nube? Pero deberias ver como obtener el log de ese lugar para detectar cual es exactamente el error  ya que HTTP 500 es generico.

Comment: Buenos días. Publico en un servidor de 1 and 1 donde están instaladas todas las librerías para CORE. Creo que es un tema de seguridad dado cuando realizo las pruebas en local responde rápido y cuando hago las pruebas en el entorno web da error.

Comment: Puede ser varios temas ya que el error generico 500 es un error del lado del servidor. Seria bueno que puedas ver el logo de dicho servidor.  Pero no comentaste que server es ? cloud? onpremise? IIS? Si tienes acceso al servidor on-premise puedes verificar el Visor de Eventos y comentarnos que errores aparece alli.

Comment: Esta colgado en el servidor de Windows que suministra 1and1, IONOS. No tengo acceso al visor de eventos. Sospecho que viene por algún tema de seguridad que en local no lo tengo y si cuando la aplicación está publicada a la hora de hacer una petición con una API a la página de catastro (está en el código) igual algo que hay que añadir al fichero.htaccess